# How to use `Buffer` in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I tried using `gray-matter` in electron, but there was `utils.js:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`. Is there a way to use `Buffer` in electron?

Comment: Are you trying to use it in the front-end or back-end of your electron app?

Comment: Buffer is a node.js module not a front-end one

Comment: I'm trying to use it in the front-end. Can't I use gray-matter in front-end?

Comment: no you can not according to the docs try it in your backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably well past being useful for the original poster, but figure I'll offer what I can for those who found this like I did.

While I'm not using gray-matter in my project, I ran into a similar issue with exposing NodeJS's Buffer object for my Electron front-end (React in my case). Easiest way is exposing the Buffer object through the use of Electron preload script.

In the preload.js

```
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('nodeAPI', {
    createBuffer: (data) => Buffer.from(data)
});
```

And then in your front end reference it like below.

```
const buffer = window.nodeAPI.createBuffer(event.target.result);
```

In case its useful for someone else too, here's a full use of it for getting a file from the frontend when retrieved from a subcomponent to a backend method for database storage.

```
     const uploadFile = async (fileName, file) => {
          if(file){
               const reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onload = async (event) => {
                    const buffer = window.nodeAPI.createBuffer(event.target.result);
                    try{
                         await window.electronAPI.addFile({
                              fileName: fileName,
                              file: buffer
                         });
                    }catch(err){
                         console.error('Error adding file: ', err);
                    }
               };
               reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          }else{
               alert('Error saving file.');
          }
     };
```